# Spark master and worker seem to run on different JVM version

Tags: apache-spark

In standalone mode master process uses `/usr/bin/java` which resolves to JVM 1.8 and worker process `/usr/lib/jvm/java/bin/java` which resolves to 1.7. In my Spark application I'm using some APIs introduced in 1.8.

Looking at stack trace one line that comes up is: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class SomeClassDefinedByMe` which internally creates instance from `java.time` which I believe is only in JDK 1.8.

How do I force worker to use JVM 1.8?

**Update**:
For now I renamed `/usr/lib/jvm/java/bin/java` and created a link that points to `/usr/bin/java`. This solved the problem but still would like to know why both processes use different binary location and where is this set.

Answer (score 1):

On each Worker node, edit `${SPARK_HOME}/conf/spark-env.sh` and define the appropriate `$JAVA_HOME` e.g.

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java`

That file is sourced by `${SPARK_HOME}/bin/load-spark-env.sh` which is invoked by each and every Spark command-line utility:

- `${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-shell` via `${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-class`
- `${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit`  via `${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-class`
- ...
- `${SPARK_HOME}/sbin/start-slave.sh`
- ...

---

Side note: the Linux `alternatives` are the standard way to define which JVM is on top of your PATH...

*Typical setup with a "fixed" setting, not relying on the priority set by the OpenJDK RPM install:*

```
$ ls -AFl $(which java)
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 22 Feb 15 16:06 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java*

$ alternatives --display java | grep -v slave
java - status is manual.
 link currently points to /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_92/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java - priority 18091
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java - priority 16000
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_92/jre/bin/java - priority 18092
Current `best' version is /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_92/jre/bin/java.
```

...provided that `$PATH` is defined properly for the Linux account that launches the Spark slaves!